# Isolate PC on my network

Tags: windows, networking, router, remote-access

The scenario I have is that I work from home for a few clients. For one of these clients, I have purchased a separate machine, and use this for any activities related to this client.

From this machine, I have some remote connection software, which allows me to access my client's servers to perform releases etc.

To allow me to connect, it has to install an 'agent' on my machine. At first, this wasn't a problem, but then I noticed that this agent made it possible to connect back to my machine through a remote connection, and also install software remotely onto my machine.

If they now have full access to my machine through the 'agent', then I'm guessing that they will also have full access to my local network, and all the devices on it.

I'm not suggesting that this company will do anything bad on my machine or network, but I have things like Media Server, SANs, Network Cameras, Sound Systems, TVs etc, which would then be available externally.

Is there any way to configure my network to prevent that machine from accessing any resources on it? I doubt that it would be a setting on the machine itself, as they already have control of this machine, and could just modify any settings.

I guess this would be similar to allowing friends/neighbours to connect to your network, but not granting them access to other resource on it.

I realise that I might be being a bit paranoid, but I'm very wary of opening up my network to external access.

Comment: do you have guest wifi on your router?  use that.

Comment: @JacobEvans, that sounds ideal, unfortunately my router doesn't have this option :-(

Comment: a VM alone isn't going to help since you're likely going to NAT the device behind your machine giving it more security from you, not the reverse....you could add a firewall or upgrade your router (maybe load DDWRT, what do you have?)

Answer (score 3):

I think Jacob Evans is on the right track with his comment.  I'd consider investing in a second router that has a guest wifi option or otherwise will allow you to VLAN the separate machine that you use for your client.  (DDWRT and Tomato both allow this, if you're willing to flash the new router.  Make sure that the hardware you buy is supported by the software you're thinking of using, of course.)

As for the VM option, well.  I'm just going to leave [this](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/03/hack-that-escapes-vm-by-exploiting-edge-browser-fetches-105000-at-pwn2own/) here:  [Virtual machine escape fetches $105,000 at Pwn2Own hacking contest](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/03/hack-that-escapes-vm-by-exploiting-edge-browser-fetches-105000-at-pwn2own/).  (I don't think it's common, but it's apparently possible.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options at least:

- configure your home router (if you have one) or your machine to allow only connections that originate from inside your network, this way you will be able to get the connectivity with the remote network, and they won't.
- install a hypervisor on your machine (like virtualbox), create the VM, install the agent inside it, and filter this VM cionnections. This way the harm will be isolated withing this VM only (considering you won't allow the VM to connect to your home network).

Comment: My router is a standard one provided by my ISP, and doesn't have many configuration options. I will try the VM option, but won't that have the same issue that it will reside on my network?

Comment: A secure boot VM will prevent them from changing the PC to install a rootkit, and while it would reside on the network, you can configure the firewall to block outbound connections to your network.  You can also ensure hat you always log in without admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a VM.

I think @[drookie](https://serverfault.com/users/165991/drookie)'s recommendations are both good ones.

However:

- you seem to be assuming the company that requested you install that agent have good security hygiene. That may well be warranted, but in general, it seems like a risky assumption. Meaning that while 'the company' might not do anything bad themselves, someone able to compromise their environment could
- you further say they

  > have full access to my machine through the 'agent'

  It might be the paranoia, but 'full access' sounds a little concerning, and if accurate, would to me justify the (fairly minor) effort of setting up a VM to avoid (bad things can happen when DNS gets changed, or proxies configured... not to mention any implications for your privacy).
- Trying to limit their access while maintaining yours, without using a VM, sounds a little complicated. Limiting their access when you have a VM sounds much easier (and besides, by using a VM, you are already limiting their access to anything you do with your system that doesn't directly relate to your working relationship with them).

Using a VM would not absolve you of ensuring your various internal services are adequately protected (i.e. access isn't *solely* dependent on your source IP).

But using one would definitely make creating the right firewall rules a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This is very dependent on your internet hardware, but some cable modems now have more than one Ethernet port (mine has four), and built-in NAT.  I also have my own NAT router on the internal side of the modem, which means I'm doing double NAT.  Conceivably, I could plug a second router into one of the other ports on the cable modem, and then I would have 2 internal LANs which are completely isolated from each other.

If that isn't a possibility for you, there are higher-grade routers available which allow you greater control over the traffic flow.  Granted, they are a bit pricey, but some people are willing to pay a premium to satisfy their paranoia.

Comment: I'm doing double NAT, too, but I'm using Tomato on my personal router to create a separate VLAN for my IoIT (Internet of Insecure Things) devices.  They're not allowed to talk to the LAN with my desktop, etc.